# Best Method to Find Multiple String Occurrences in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, find

I need to be pointed in the right direction for this problem I'm working on:

Let's say I'm reading output from a C program as follows:

```
while True:
    ln = p.stdout.readline()
    if '' == ln:
        break
    #do stuff here with ln
```

And my output looks like this line for line:

```
TrnIq: Thread on CPU 37
TrnIq: Thread on CPU 37 but will be moved to CPU 44
IP-Thread on CPU 33
FANOUT Thread on CPU 37
Filter-Thread on CPU 38 but will be moved to CPU 51
TRN TMR Test 2 Supervisor Thread on CPU 34
HomographyWarp Traking Thread[0] on CPU 26
```

I want to capture "TrnIq: Thread on" and "37" as 2 separate variables: a string and a number from output "TrnIq: Thread on CPU 37".

Its pretty well the same for the other lines to, for example capture "HomographyWarp Traking Thread[0] on" and the # "26" from "HomographyWarp Traking Thread[0] on CPU 26".

The only real challenge is for lines like this: "Filter-Thread on CPU 38 but will be moved to CPU 51" on this line I need "Filer-Thread" and the # "51" not the first # "38".

Python has so many different ways to do this I dont even know where to start!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regex seems like overkill to me here.  [Disclaimer: I don't like regular expressions, but do like Python, so where possible I write in Python, and don't write regular expressions.  For reasons I've never fully understood this is considered surprising.]

```
s = """TrnIq: Thread on CPU 37
TrnIq: Thread on CPU 37 but will be moved to CPU 44
IP-Thread on CPU 33
FANOUT Thread on CPU 37
Filter-Thread on CPU 38 but will be moved to CPU 51
TRN TMR Test 2 Supervisor Thread on CPU 34
HomographyWarp Traking Thread[0] on CPU 26"""

for line in s.splitlines():
    words = line.split()
    if not ("CPU" in words and "on" in words): continue # skip uninteresting lines
    prefix_words = words[:words.index("on")+1]
    prefix = ' '.join(prefix_words)
    cpu = int(words[-1])
    print (prefix, cpu)
```

gives

```
('TrnIq: Thread on', 37)
('TrnIq: Thread on', 44)
('IP-Thread on', 33)
('FANOUT Thread on', 37)
('Filter-Thread on', 51)
('TRN TMR Test 2 Supervisor Thread on', 34)
('HomographyWarp Traking Thread[0] on', 26)
```

and I don't think I need to translate any of this code into English.

Comment: Yes! Even I can understand it just by looking at it! Much simpler than regular expressions! but which way is more efficient in you opinion?

Comment: What's efficiency?  I think of it as something like a measure of total time -- time writing, time debugging, time running, time modifying it to handle a case I didn't predict -- to get the output I need.  Regexps will usually (not always) win on performance.  I think they only win on the code side for use cases I seldom find myself in -- a little too complex for basic tools and not complex enough to justify using a real parser -- but opinions and situations vary.

Comment: That's because there's a line you're reading in your real case that doesn't contain the word "on", even though every example line you gave has one.  What is the line in question?  (Just add `print line` inside the loop.)

Comment: `while True:
    s = p.stdout.readline()
    if '' == s:
        break
        for line in s.splitlines():
            words = line.split()
            prefix_words = words[:words.index("on")+1]
            prefix = ' '.join(prefix_words)
            cpu = int(words[-1])
            print (prefix, cpu)`

Comment: No, I mean that there's a line that the C program is spitting out which *doesn't contain the word "on"*.  That's why it can't find it.  For example, if you had a line which was "Waiting for results.." or something.  It's easy to skip lines that don't have "CPU" and "on" in them; I'll modify to show it.

Comment: Ohh!! I see, well I guess I should have clarified the fact that these are just the output lines I am interested in. There are thousands of other lines: _process_trn_ip_rslts: Switching to TRN_FILTER_PROPAGATING state. trn_filter: total_update_timer = 0.057454 seconds. trn_ib->trn_ib_state.ip_part=1 DISPOSITION ACCEPT VALUE = 2 -a *_000004.pgm Disposition ACCEPT frame 4 sent to socket 6 TrnIb: Sending image id=(1003080551, 750074, framecnt 4) to IP via socket=8 from IB. open_sock/bind OK, sock=79 create_cmd_sock/listen OK, erc=0 trn_filter, instance 3: socket_from_cmd: 35_

Comment: Where am I supposed to define "s"?

Answer (score 4):

The following should return a tuple of the information assuming `ln` is a single line of your data (edited to include converting the CPU value to an int):

```
match = re.match(r'(.*?)(?: on CPU.*)?(?: (?:on|to) CPU )(.*)', ln).groups()
if match:
    proc, cpu = match.groups()
    cpu = int(cpu)
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> for ln in lines:
...     print re.match(r'(.*?)(?: on CPU.*)?(?: (?:on|to) CPU )(.*)', ln).groups()
... 
('TrnIq: Thread', '37')
('TrnIq: Thread', '44')
('IP-Thread', '33')
('FANOUT Thread', '37')
('Filter-Thread', '51')
('TRN TMR Test 2 Supervisor Thread', '34')
('HomographyWarp Traking Thread[0]', '26')
```

Explanation:

```
(.*?)          # capture zero or more characters at the start of the string,
               #   as few characters as possible
(?: on CPU.*)? # optionally match ' on CPU' followed by any number of characters,
               #   do not capture this
(?: (?:on|to) CPU )  # match ' on CPU ' or ' to CPU ', but don't capture
(.*)           # capture the rest of the line
```

Rubular: http://www.rubular.com/r/HqS9nGdmbM

Comment: So this will return a tuple containing 2 strings for each line? If I wanted to convert the #s to strings, does python have a strToNum function?

Comment: @NASAIntern - You could change the `.*` at the end to `\d+` so that instead of grabbing the rest of the line you are sure that you only grab digits.  Then you can just use the `int()` built-in function to convert the strings to numbers.

Comment: Just for futurue use, would you mind explaining this line some more: I get the regular expression chararters, but tnt how the function works exactly: roc, cpu = re.match(r'(.*?)(?: on CPU.*)?(?: (?:on|to) CPU )(.*)', ln).groups()

Comment: No idea why you're downvoted, your answer is correct and well explained.  +1.  This is super minor, but it might be nice to have an `import re` line somewhere in your code, just to add a bit of clarity.

Comment: @NASAIntern - `re.match()` returns a [MatchObject](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject), and [MatchObject.groups()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups) returns a tuple of the captured groups from the regex.  The `proc, cpu = ...` is called [sequence unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), and is basically the same as `groups = re.match(...).groups(); proc = groups[0]; cpu = groups[1]`.

Comment: I keep getting an error on: proc, cpu = re.match(r'(.*?)(?: on CPU.*)?(?: (?:on|to) CPU )(.*)', ln).groups()

Comment: `while True:
    ln = p.stdout.readline()
    if '' == ln:
        break
        print ln
        proc, cpu = re.match(r'(.*?)(?: on CPU.*)?(?: (?:on|to) CPU )(.*)', ln).groups()
        cpu = int(cpu)
        for ln in lines:
            print re.match(r'(.*?)(?: on CPU.*)?(?: (?:on|to) CPU )(.*)', ln).groups()`

Comment: I guess I should have clarified the fact that these are just the output lines I am interested in. There are thousands of other lines: 

_process_trn_ip_rslts: Switching to TRN_FILTER_PROPAGATING state.
trn_filter: total_update_timer = 0.057454 seconds.
trn_ib->trn_ib_state.ip_part=1
DISPOSITION ACCEPT VALUE = 2
-a *_000004.pgm
Disposition ACCEPT frame 4 sent to socket 6
TrnIb: Sending image id=(1003080551, 750074, framecnt 4) to IP via socket=8 from IB.
open_sock/bind OK, sock=79
create_cmd_sock/listen OK, erc=0
trn_filter, instance 3: socket_from_cmd: 35_

Comment: You might need to do this in two steps, if some lines don't match that pattern, first save the result of `re.match(...)` into a variable called match, and then only do `proc, cpu = match.groups()` if `match` is not `None`.

Answer (score 1):

So use regex `^(.*?)\s+on\s+CPU.*(?<=\sCPU)\s+(\d+)\s*$`

```
import sys
import re

for ln in sys.stdin:
  m = re.match(r'^(.*?)\s+on\s+CPU.*(?<=\sCPU)\s+(\d+)\s*$', ln); 
  if m is not None:
    print m.groups();
```

See and test the example [here](http://ideone.com/uKfgO).

Comment: I guess I should have clarified the fact that these are just the output lines I am interested in. There are thousands of other lines: 

_process_trn_ip_rslts: Switching to TRN_FILTER_PROPAGATING state.
trn_filter: total_update_timer = 0.057454 seconds.
trn_ib->trn_ib_state.ip_part=1
DISPOSITION ACCEPT VALUE = 2
-a *_000004.pgm
Disposition ACCEPT frame 4 sent to socket 6
TrnIb: Sending image id=(1003080551, 750074, framecnt 4) to IP via socket=8 from IB.
open_sock/bind OK, sock=79
create_cmd_sock/listen OK, erc=0
trn_filter, instance 3: socket_from_cmd: 35_

Comment: @NASAIntern - If you need print entire lines, just replace `print m.groups();` with `print ln;` – Ωmega 5 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

In the case you mention, you always want the second CPU number, so it can be done with a single regexp:

```
# Test program
import re

lns = [
    "TrnIq: Thread on CPU 37",
    "TrnIq: Thread on CPU 37 but will be moved to CPU 44",
    "IP-Thread on CPU 33",
    "FANOUT Thread on CPU 37",
    "Filter-Thread on CPU 38 but will be moved to CPU 51",
    "TRN TMR Test 2 Supervisor Thread on CPU 34",
    "HomographyWarp Traking Thread[0] on CPU 26"
]

for ln in lns:
    test    = re.search("(?P<process>.*Thread\S* on).* CPU (?P<cpu>\d+)$", ln)
    print "%s: '%s' on CPU #%s" % ( ln, test.group('process'), test.group('cpu'))
```

In the general case maybe you want to distinguish between cases (e.g. thread on a CPU, moved thread, subthread...). To do this, you can employ several re.search()es one after another. For example:

```
# This search recognizes lines of the form "...Thread on CPU so-and-so", and
# also lines that add "...but will be moved to CPU some-other-cpu".
test = re.search("(?P<process>.* Thread) on CPU (?P<cpu1>\d+)( but will be moved to CPU (?P<cpu2>\d+))*", ln)
if test:
   # Here we capture Process Thread, both moved and non moved
   if test.group('cpu2'):
       # We have process, cpu1 and cpu2: moved thread
   else:
       # Nonmoved task, we have test.group('process') and cpu1.
else:
   # No match, try some other regexp. For example processes with a thread number
   # between square brackets: "Thread[0]", which are not captured by the regex above.
   test = re.search("(?P<process>.*) Thread[(?P<thread>\d+)] on CPU (?P<cpu1>)", ln)
   if test:
       # Here we have Homography Traking in process, 0 in thread, 26 in cpu1
```

For optimum performance, tests for lines that occur more frequently are best done first.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the 2nd part in "You can then do this with several re.search(). For example:" What would I use this for?

Comment: I guess I should have clarified the fact that these are just the output lines I am interested in. There are thousands of other lines: _process_trn_ip_rslts: Switching to TRN_FILTER_PROPAGATING state. trn_filter: total_update_timer = 0.057454 seconds.trn_ib->trn_ib_state.ip_part=1 DISPOSITION ACCEPT VALUE = 2 -a *_000004.pgm Disposition ACCEPT frame 4 sent to socket 6 TrnIb: Sending image id=(1003080551, 750074, framecnt 4) to IP via socket=8 from IB. open_sock/bind OK, sock=79 create_cmd_sock/listen OK, erc=0 trn_filter, instance 3: socket_from_cmd: 35_

Comment: OK, then for every ln you read, you check it against one of several regexp's using re.search(). The first .search I supplied recognizes lines like "... Thread... on... CPU". The other searches are more targeted and a bit more efficient. If you have a very common line you're NOT interested in, you might also try to recognize it in order to discard it and save the subsequent comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done pretty simply with two regex searches:

```
import re

while True:
    ln = p.stdout.readline()
    if '' == ln:
        break

    start_match = re.search(r'^(.*?) on', ln)
    end_match = re.search(r'(\d+)$', ln)
    process = start_match and start_match.group(0)
    process_number = end_match and end_match.group(0)
```

Comment: Can you provide some detail on this? I'm still getting used to python's syntax for this kinda stuff?

Comment: You can read through Python's Regular Expression module documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: I get the regular expressions, just not the "and" and match.group() functions. matchgroup() returns a string right?

Comment: Ah, the `and` is in case no match is found.  `group()` will return any specified capture groups as strings, in this case since we only have one we call `group(0)`.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified the fact that these are just the output lines I am interested in. There are thousands of other lines: 

`process_trn_ip_rslts: Switching to TRN_FILTER_PROPAGATING state.
trn_filter: total_update_timer = 0.057454 seconds.
trn_ib->trn_ib_state.ip_part=1
DISPOSITION ACCEPT VALUE = 2
-a *_000004.pgm
Disposition ACCEPT frame 4 sent to socket 6
TrnIb: Sending image id=(1003080551, 750074, framecnt 4) to IP via socket=8 from IB.
open_sock/bind OK, sock=79
create_cmd_sock/listen OK, erc=0
trn_filter, instance 3: socket_from_cmd: 35~